# Вывод в Toast содержания 2х файлов [android]

Tags: android

Всем привет, есть код вывода содержания текстового файла в тоаст. Подскажите, как его переделать, что бы он выводил в тот же тоаст содержание ещё одного файла. тоесть 2х файлов сразу. необходимо оставить фоновое чтение и AsyncTask. разрешения на интернет в манифесте добавлены.

```
package com.example.uinpass;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import com.example.uinpass.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.*;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Button btnSend;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final Button btnSend = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(final View v)
                {new ReadInBackground("http://мой-сайт.ру/text.txt").execute();

                }
            });

}
        public static String executeHttpGet(String uri) throws Exception
        {

            String result = "";
            try
            {

                URL url = new URL(uri);            
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String str;
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                   result +=str;
                }
                in.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
         private class ReadInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
            {
                String url = "";
                public ReadInBackground(String ur)
                {
                    url = ur;
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Void... voids)
                {
            //тут выполняется после завершения фонового потока в основном
                    //тут все выполняется в фоновом потоке
                    try {
                        return executeHttpGet(url);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return url;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String params)
                {

           Teoast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), params,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                }
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ваш исправленный код, прокомментировал, где поправил

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Button btnSend;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final Button btnSend = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            // делается массив, чтобы можно было вручную инициализировать его
            final Sting[] urls = new Sting[]{"http://мой-сайт.ру/text.txt","http://мой-сайт.ру/text_1.txt","http://мой-сайт.ру/text_2.txt"};
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(final View v)
                {
                //тут я просто сделал преобразование в List, если надо можешь поменять как надо
                    List<String> strs = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(urls);
                    new ReadInBackground(strs).execute();

                }
            });

}
        public static String executeHttpGet(String uri) throws Exception
        {

            String result = "";
            try
            {

                URL url = new URL(uri);            
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                String str;
                while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                   result +=str;
                }
                in.close();
            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
         private class ReadInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>>
            {
                List<String> listUrl = "";
                //тут передается List ссылок на текстовый файлы
                public ReadInBackground(List<String> urs)
                {
                    listUrl = new ArrayList<String>(urs);
                }

                @Override
                protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... voids)
                {

                    //тут все выполняется в фоновом потоке

                    List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>();
                    try 
                    {
                        //пробегаемся по всем ссылками и получаем содержимое файлов
                        for(String string:listUrl)
                        {
                            listString.add(executeHttpGet(string));
                            listSting.add(executeHttpGet(string));
                        }

                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //тут мы в любом случае отправим не null, так как проинициализировали
                    return listString;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(List<String> params)
                {
                //тут выполняется после завершения фонового потока в основном
                    Sting toastMsg = "";
                    //а тут пробегаемся по содержимому всех файлов
                    //и преобразуем его к одной строке
                    for(String string:params)
                    {
                        toastMsg += string + "\n";//по хорошему тут надо делать через StringBuilder 
                    }
                    Teoast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastMsg,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: спасибо,вот у вас toastMsg включает в себя содержание всех файлов. мне нужно будет в дальнейшем использовать разные переменные для каждого из содержания файлов. тоесть как сделать, что бы содержанию http://мой-сайт.ру/text.txt соответствовала переменная toastMsg, а одержанию http://мой-сайт.ру/text_2.txt соответствовала переменная toastMsg2

Comment: toastMsg  формируется из List<String> params, там 
params.get(i) -  содержимое i-го файла

Comment: вот так будет?
String toastMsg = params.get(1);
String toastMsg2 = params.get(2);  только вот тут разобраться не могу  
 toastMsg += string + "\n";//по хорошему тут надо делать через StringBuilder

Comment: нет, вторая часть лишняя
for(String string:params) { toastMsg = string; toastMsg2 = string; }  
почитайте как работать в java с List<T>